# If I want to transfer a resource, which kind of parameter type should I choose? weak_ptr? or shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, parameters, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

There is a resource: "aaa", who's type is "AAA".
"aaa" is managed by shared_ptr, and we can get it's weak_ptr by function:

```
std::weak_ptr<AAA> get_aaa_weakPtr();
```

Now, the client_code want to visit "aaa", and transfer "aaa" to it's child_functions. 
Just like this:

```
void mainFunc(){

std::shared_ptr<AAA> sPtr = get_aaa_weakPtr().lock();
assert( sPtr );
// use sPtr
// ...

childFuncA( /* also_need_aaa */ );
childFuncB( /* also_need_aaa */ );
childFuncC( /* also_need_aaa */ );
}
```

which kind of parameter type should I choose in child_functions?
weak_ptr? or shared_ptr?

Comment: The `assert()` is likely wrong.

Comment: @Deduplicator  What about: "assert( sPtr!=nullptr );" ?

Comment: The problem is that it looks reasonably likely that the pointer actually *is* null.

Answer (score 0):

In case of concurrent programming, i.e. childFuncX can be async, you should pass a weak_ptr and, inside the function, check for the validity of the pointer (with weak_ptr::lock()) and ensure single access to the resource with a std::lock_guard of a mutex, which in you case can be instantiated directly in the main function (or unique_lock as your needs). Avoid global and static to avoid future issues as software evolve over time.

Comment: Great thanks for your suggestion. I think weak_ptr is reliable.